# How to make Graphical Applications in Deno?

Tags: typescript, user-interface, libraries, deno

I need to make GUI in Deno, but I could not find any option except WebView, which comes with a few caveats. There seems to be about tauri-apps on GitHub, but looking at their website, it doesn't look it will come out soon. What other options exist?

Comment: Deno natively support [WebGPU](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/WebGPU) (Experimental) [read more](https://deno.land/posts/v1.8#experimental-support-for-the-webgpu-api), Or Are you trying to do server-side rendering ?

Comment: Tauri is the most mature option at present.